# Combination of Binary sequences

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of binary sequences of length 10 in which ‘1’ occurs in blocks of even sizes.

My attempt:

Do it with multiple cases where k represent the number of '1's such that k = 0,2,4,6,8,10.

**Case k=0:**

1 way, where all is zeroes

**Case k = 2:**

The beginning of the 1's could be from position 1 till 9.

Hence, $C^9_1$

**Case k=4**

When the 1's appears as a block of 4, it could be from position 1 till 7.

Hence, $C^7_1$

When the 1's appear as 2 blocks of 2, how do i do this?

Comment: Hint:  You can take any string of length $9$ and set the last digit to make the number of $1's$ even.

Comment: Side note: it's a really, really good idea to start with shorter strings.  Do length $1$, then $2$, $3$.  You'll see a clear pattern in the answers.

Comment: @lulu: I don't think the OP is asking for an even number of ones, but for the ones to occur in blocks of even size. $1110001101$, for instance, wouldn't count, since there's a block with length $3$ and one with length $1$.

Comment: Hint: Every non-empty string satisfying the required property consists of a smaller non-empty string satisfying the property, followed by one of the strings 11, 00, or 110.  That should be enough to find a recurrence relation and solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I meant every string of length at least 2.

Comment: @Mastrem  I think you are correct, I misread.   In that case, the problem directs us to look at binary words in $0,11$.

Comment: we never study recurrence relations

Answer (score 1):

Following lulus comment, a string in the symbols '0' and '11' of length $10-k$ with $k$ '11' symbols is a valid string, giving

$$\sum_{k=0}^5 \binom{10-k}{k} = 89$$

valid strings.

Answer (score 1):

We start with describing the set of *all* binary strings built from the alphabet $V=\{0,1\}$:

These are strings starting with zero or more $0$'s:$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \longrightarrow 0^*$

followed by zero or more occurrences of $1$ followed by zero or more $0$'s: $\ \qquad \longrightarrow (10^*)^*$

> We obtain the following representation of all binary strings:
>
> \begin{align*}0^*(10^*)^*\end{align*}
>
> Since we want to consider all binary strings with $1$ occurring in blocks of even size, we substitute $1$ with $11$ and obtain
>
> \begin{align*}0^*(\color{blue}{11}0^*)^*\tag{1}\end{align*}
>
> The regular expression (1) generates all valid words in a *unique* manner. In such cases we can use it to derive a generating function $$A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$$ with
>   $a_n$ giving the number of valid words of length $n$.

In order to do so all we need to know is the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* since the $star$ operator
\begin{align*}
0^*=\left(\varepsilon|0|00|000|\cdots\right)\qquad\text{ translates to }\qquad 1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-z}
\end{align*}

> We obtain by translating the regular expression in the language of generating functions (and by mixing up somewhat the symbolic to provide some intermediate steps)
>
> \begin{align*}
> 0^*(\color{blue}{11}0^*)^*
> &\longrightarrow \quad \frac{1}{1-z}\left(\frac{z^2}{1-z}\right)^*\\
> &\longrightarrow \quad \frac{1}{1-z}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{1-z}}\right)\\
> &\quad\quad=\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude: The number of valid words is given by the generating function $A(z)$
>   \begin{align*}
> A(z)&=\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}\\
> &=1+z+2z^2+3z^3+5z^4+\color{blue}{8}z^5+13z^6\\
> &\qquad+21z^7+34z^8+55z^9+\color{red}{89}z^{10}+144z^{11}+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>
> The expansion was done with the help of Wolfram Alpha. We see that e.g. the number of valid words of length $10$ is $89$.

We see, the coefficient of $z^5$ is $8$.
So, out of $2^5=32$ binary words of length $5$ there are $8$ valid words which are marked blue in the table below.

\begin{array}{cccc}
\color{blue}{00000}&01000&10000&\color{blue}{11000}\\
00001&01001&10001&11001\\
00010&01010&10010&11010\\
\color{blue}{00011}&01011&10011&\color{blue}{11011}\\
00100&\color{blue}{01100}&10100&11100\\
00101&01101&10101&11101\\
\color{blue}{00110}&01110&10110&\color{blue}{11110}\\
00111&\color{blue}{01111}&10111&11111\\
\end{array}

> **Note:** The generating function $A(z)$ determines the *[Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)* so that the number $a_n$ of valid strings of length $n$ is given by the recurrence relation
>   \begin{align*}
> &a_0=1,a_1=1\\
> &a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}\qquad\qquad n\geq 2
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

As Mitchell Spector pointed out, Every string of length at least $2$ satisfying the property consists of a smaller string satsifying the property followed by $11$, $00$ or $110$.
so:
$$a_n=2a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$$
Also, $$a_0=1,a_1=1,a_2=2$$
We obtain $a_{10}=89$.